# Use Generics with Mock Setup()?

Tags: c#, generics, moq

I am setting up unit test for a project with Many Databases & Tables. I am attempting to make a generic method for each of the DB context so that we don't have to have the same method for every table / view we have. This is my first time trying to build something with Generics.

I need to replace the `context.setup(x => x.pricelists)` which should be of Type T . I am going to post my working non generic code and then my generic code which of course is not working

**Working Code : Non Generic**

```
 public static void ConfigurePriceList(List<VRI.DB.Rivet.Entities.PriceList> PriceList, Mock<IRivetContext> context)
        {
            var priceList = PriceList.AsQueryable();
            var priceListMockSet = new Mock<DbSet<VRI.DB.Rivet.Entities.PriceList>>();
            priceListMockSet.As<IQueryable<VRI.DB.Rivet.Entities.PriceList>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(priceList.Provider);
            priceListMockSet.As<IQueryable<VRI.DB.Rivet.Entities.PriceList>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(priceList.Expression);
            priceListMockSet.As<IQueryable<VRI.DB.Rivet.Entities.PriceList>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(priceList.ElementType);
            priceListMockSet.As<IQueryable<VRI.DB.Rivet.Entities.PriceList>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(priceList.GetEnumerator());
            context.Setup(x => x.PriceLists).Returns(priceListMockSet.Object);
        }
```

**Not Working Generic Code**

```
 public static void AddDataToContext<T>(List<T> DataList, Mock<IRivetContext> context) where T : class
        {
            var dataList = DataList.AsQueryable();
            var dataListMockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>(); 
            dataListMockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Provider).Returns(dataList.Provider);
            dataListMockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.Expression).Returns(dataList.Expression);
            dataListMockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.ElementType).Returns(dataList.ElementType);
            dataListMockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(dataList.GetEnumerator());
            context.Setup(x => x.PriceLists).Returns(dataListMockSet.Object); // Need to make the table (x.priceLists) generic
        }
```

Comment: You mention your code is "not working". How do you know it's not working? Are you getting an exception? Are you not seeing the right results? Are the tests failing? Please post exception information including all the relevant stack.

Answer (score 0):

the following is about 5 years old and will work UNTIL you want to use any of the newer async methods in EF -- it is usually simpler to use the EF Core In-Memory Database provider (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli):

```cs
    public static class IQueryableExtensions
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage( "Microsoft.Design", "CA1065", Justification = " caused by an exception declaration instead of a thrown exception")]
        private static readonly TestException testException = new TestException("testing auto-generated exception");

        public static Mock<DbSet<T>> GetMockSet<T>(this IQueryable<T> entities, bool throwDuringWhere = false)
            where T : class
        {
            var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
            mockSet
                .As<IQueryable<T>>()
                .Setup(m => m.Provider)
                .Returns(entities.Provider);
            mockSet
                .As<IQueryable<T>>()
                .Setup(m => m.Expression)
                .Returns(() =>
                {
                    if (throwDuringWhere)
                    {
                        throw testException;
                    }

                    return entities.Expression;
                });
            mockSet
                .As<IQueryable<T>>()
                .Setup(m => m.ElementType)
                .Returns(entities.ElementType);
            mockSet
                .As<IQueryable<T>>()
                .Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator())
                .Returns(entities.GetEnumerator());

            return mockSet;
        }
```

the newer approach looks something like this

```cs
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();
        builder.UseInMemoryDatabase(QueryTestsBase.DatabaseName);
        builder.UseInternalServiceProvider(this.ServiceProvider);

        this.ServiceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .AddDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>(optionsBuilder =>
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseInternalServiceProvider(this.ServiceProvider);
                optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(QueryTestsBase.DatabaseName);

                this.DbContextOptions = (DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>)optionsBuilder.Options;
            })
            .AddScoped<ApplicationDbContext>(_ => this.ApplicationDbContext!)
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        this.ApplicationDbContext = this.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>>().CreateDbContext();
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply but that did not actually answer the question. My question was in regard to the line that you removed.  "context.Setup(x => x.PriceLists).Returns(dataListMockSet.Object);" In that line i was wanting to know if the .setup could be made generic. The type of T is the same type that is being accessed in x.PriceList so i assume it is possible I just can't figure it out

Comment: mock.Object is already `DbSet<T>`

Comment: if I am understanding your follow-up, IRivetContext needs to be generic

Comment: So that line sets what gets returned when the table in the setup is called IE: x.PriceLists returns the list in the .return . So I need a generic way of telling it what the "table" is. so it might be x.priceLists or it could be x.ReferralSource. So i need a way to express x.<T> inside of that expression. Sorry if this is not making since, it is hard to talk about something you don't fully understand.